# iOS Table view cell not displaying properly after resize

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have set up my table view with 6 static cells and I'm trying to have one cell (the third cell) expand upon selection. The problem is, it resizes after calling `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:`, but then the cell appears blank. If I scroll the cell out of view, it shows the contents properly.

When I call `[tableView reloadData]` the cell isn't blank, but then, I can't enjoy the animation.

Does anyone know why this is so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I was the only one having the problem with a blank static cell issue.
I stumbled on a solution and that is calling `[tableView reloadData]` after calling `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:`

Answer (score 1):

Well if you set the height for a row then you need to reload the content of the cell NOT the content of the whole table. If you call [tableview reloadData] then it simply means that you redraw the whole table(without the height correction).

To reload a single cell in the table:

```
[tableView beginUpdates];
[tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
[tableView endUpdates];
```

Comment: Oh, my bad. I meant to say, the cell appears blank after calling `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:` I'll edit the question

Answer (score 0):

- Reload the respective table view row using the main thread.

> [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
>
> ```
>     // Reload the respective table view row using the main thread.
>     [self.tblFiles reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:index inSection:0]]
>                          withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
>     
> }];
> ```